# Pseudocode of sorting a list of strings without using loops

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I was trying to think of an algorithm that would sort a list of strings according to its first 4 chars (say each line from a file), without using the conventional looping methods such as `while`,`for`. An example of inputs would be:

> 1231COME1900123
>   1233COME1902030
>   2031COME1923919
>   1231GO  1231203
>   1233GO  1932911
>   2031GO  1239391

The thing is, we do not know the number of records there can be beforehand. And each 4-digit ID number can have multiple `COME` and `GO` records. But they are sorted as above beforehand. And I want to sort the file by their 4-digit ID number. And achieve this:

> 1231COME1900123
>   1231GO  1231203
>   1233COME1902030
>   1233GO  1932911
>   2031COME1923919
>   2031GO  1239391

The only logical comment I can have is that we should be using a recursive way to read through the records, but the sorting part is a bit tricky for me. Also `GOTO` could be used as well. Any ideas?

Comment: With GOTO you can emulate every `while`- and `for`-loop quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 1st 4 characters of each entry are always digits, you do something as follows:

1. Create a list of length 10000, where each element can hold a pair of values.
2. Enter into that element of the list based upon the first 4 digits.
3. The shape of the individual elements will be as follows -> **[COME_ELEMENT, GO_ELEMENT]**.
4. Each **COME_ELEMENT** and **GO_ELEMENT** is a list in itself, of length equal to the maximum value + 1 that can appear after the words **COME** & **GO**.
5. Now, as the string arrives break it at the 1st 4 digits. Now, go to that element of the list.
6. After that, check whether it's a go or come.
7. If it's a go (suppose), then determine the number after the word **go**.
8. Insert the string at the index (determined in 7th step) in the inner list.
9. When you're done with inserting values, just traverse the non-empty elements.

The result so obtained will contain the sorted order that you require without the use of looping.

Comment: Hmmm.. But there could be multiple COME and GO elements for each ID as mentioned. So wouldn't I be left with the same problem when I do your algorithm? I would only filter the list by their ID and be left with multiple COME and GO values. I hope I was clear enough with the issue in this.

Comment: Oh! yes that's right. I forgot taking that into account.

Comment: If Memory isn't a constraint, then maybe you can get a solution to it.
All you've to do is, create an array for each come and go of length which is equal to the maximum possible occurring value + 1.
You can then insert element, into this in just O(1) time.
But, this is a terrible idea to allocate this much memory beforehand.
I believe you should store the elements as they arrive and then sort them.
In this way, you'll be able to save memory at the cost of time required for sorting.

Comment: I think that would work. Can you edit your answer with your new idea? :)

Comment: @Huzo I don't understand what you mean? This should actually work if you re-build the element by simply concatenating the 4 digit value with each of the elements in the list.

Comment: @ChatterOne if you just simply follow the algo that was initially suggested, I would end up with a matrix that would look like this `[0001,[0001COME912, 0001COME939], [0001GO 932, 0001GO123, 0001GO923]]` which would mean that I have not achieved what I wanted but just filtered records according to their ID.

Comment: @Huzo Interesting, I misunderstood it then. I thought that the purpose was to end up with a count-sort that in the end gave you a map of which keys are your digits and values are a list,  like this: `{0001: [0001COME912, 0001COME939], 0002: [0001COME957, 0001COME940]}` and so on. And you don't need to care about the keys to be sorted because they're numbers and you can traverse it by a simple sequential loop.